# Getting NotFoundHttpException when accessing a image file in uploads directory in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, wamp, laravel-5

My setup

- WAMP
- Windows 8

I have an uploads directory in

- iapp <- Root Directory

  - uploads
  - app
  - public

Virtual Hosts file (httpd-vhosts.conf)

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/
        ServerName localhost
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin admin@iapp.dev
        DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/iapp/public" 
        ServerName iapp.dev
        ErrorLog "logs/iapp.dev-error.log"
        CustomLog "logs/dev-iapp.dev-access.log" common

        <Directory "/">
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 127.0.0.1
        </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
```

my htaccess file inside public diretory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My App is working **fine** but I can't access any images/files inside my uploads directory.When accessing an image or file it is throwing me this error

```
NotFoundHttpException in C:\wamp\www\iapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php line 142:
```

How do I solve this? And I also want to know which is the best place to put file uploads?

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access directories and files that are *above* the document root, that is `public`. You need to move your `uploads` directory to the `public` directory.

Comment: Yes, because it is the document root. So you would access a file by requesting `/uploads/somefile.png` in your browser.

Comment: Hey.Do you know how I can allow access to this uploads folder?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'allow access'. To who? Also, if you have a new question, please [ask it separately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: To the users.The files inside public directory are gravatar images etc.